# Kendo toolbar misbehave

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I'm having a problem implementing a toolbar for kendo grid. The problem is a partial view used to load a left-sided menu for a specific module in the website application.
So far, I have not been able to work around this, thus I'm asking here for help.

This is what the grid looks like without the left menu:
[image: withoutmenu]

This is what the grid looks like with the left menu:
[image: withmenu]

So far, this is what the menu code has:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-left" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; border-color:lightgray;">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-">
        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "FicheiroIdqa")">
                    <span class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:8px; vertical-align:middle;"></span> Ficheiros Idqa
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ZaPe")">
                    <span class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:8px; vertical-align:middle;"></span> ZaPes
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "LocalColheita")">
                    <span class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:8px; vertical-align:middle;"></span> Locais Colheita
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "FamiliaParametro")">
                    <span class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:8px; vertical-align:middle;"></span> Famílias Parâmetro
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("", "")">
                    <span class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:8px; vertical-align:middle;"></span> Editais
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Resultados")">
                    <span class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:8px; vertical-align:middle;"></span> Export. Resultados
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the code in the view, where I am calling the partial with the menu:

```
@model List<INL.InLabLimsAqua.OnlineResults.WebApp.ViewModels.FicheiroIdqaViewModel>

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Ficheiros Idqa"; }

<h5>@Html.ActionLink("Ersar", "Index", "Ersar") > @ViewBag.Title</h5>
<hr />
<div class="col-md-2" style="padding-left:0px; width:200px;">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Ersar/_ErsarMenu.cshtml")
</div>
<div class="col-md-offset-1" style="padding-left:95px;">
    ...
    grid configuration
    ...
</div>
```

I think the problem resides in the fact that the toolbar is being loaded in the same row as the left menu, and it pushes it down with its height.
Any help to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please try to put the side menu and your grid in a row and add "col-md-10" instead of  "col-md-offset-1"..

Comment: Have you tried putting the left menu and the partial view in separate columns?